# Add a New Column in Table For Order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-order-by

In my project, I have 12 tables. Let take 2 of them as sample:

```
                    SaleOrder                                      PurchaseOrder  
Date    SaleOrdId      Qty   UnitPrice   Amount ||  Date   PurchOrdId   Qty    UnitPrice     Amount
4/2/12   S_1            2      600       1200       6/2/12 P_1           50     500           25000
7/2/12   S_2            5      600       3000
```

SaleordId and Purchordid are the primary keys.
From these, I am Generating a  Product Inquiry Report like:

```
                     Product Inquiry Report
Date    TranId    QtyPurchased    QtySold  Balance 
4/2/12  S_1                        2        20 (previous)
6/2/12  P_1         50                      70
7/2/12  S_2                        5        65
```

For Now,When i Select data from both the tables by union, I use Order by 'Date'. But In practice I think it may cause problems if there is some problem with system Date and time. So what i have decided is to add an extra Column 'OrdCol' to both the tables and maintain a separate table for that and keep it primary key there like:

```
             SaleOrder     PurchaseORder                   OrderTbl
Date OrdCol  -----         Date OrdCol -----            OrdCol
      1                          2                        1
      3                                                   2
                                                          3
```

Is my idea correct in terms of DB?
Is Not, then any other idea?
I cant apply order by 'Primary keys' of the tables(SO and PO) as they are in nvarchar and there numeric 
part can be same for both.

Comment: If you worry about problems with system date and time, the order of your return set is the least problem you're facing. In such a case you would store wrong information regarding the Sales or Purchase date. Storing the "wrong" information is far more critical than to display in the wrong order... You should make sure the date information is correct. If you cannot rely on system date, the app should provide the date. And if this source isn't valid either, connect to a reliable source (e.g. on the web). The solution you're lookig for doesn't solve the issues. It just masks it.

Comment: @Lmu92 what sort of problems could be there if I use an extra order by column. Could you please explain?

Comment: If the sort order of your separate column is different than the sort order of the date column, how would you explain to the end user that the order of the result set being displayed does make any sense? (to use your example: why would it be correct to show the results in the order 4/2/12, 7/2/12, 6/2/12?

Comment: @Lmu92 it wont show a Date order which you have supposed. All the order col will be recorded according the date order

Comment: Then what will be the purpose of that additional column? How will you guarantee that the order in your separate table will always lead to an ascending order date?

Comment: @LMU ofcourse each entry in order column will be generated according to date, look if Odr_1 was generated on 1 sep, Obviously Odr_2 will be generated after this date